# Driver version unknown error while running Selenium in MAC with Safari browser.

Tags: macos, selenium, safari

- I'm running the Selenium test on Safari browser on Mac and it keeps giving me the error "Driver info: driver.version: unknown".
- The version of the grid which I'm using is "Grid Console v.3.4.0".
- The Selenium driver that I'm Using is "selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar"
- This is the logs that I'm getting while executing the test.

Here is the log

```
13:52:40.423 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{name=HelpButtonTest, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]])
13:52:40.424 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{name=HelpButtonTest, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]
13:52:40.427 INFO - Server started on port 12036
13:52:40.428 INFO - Launching Safari
13:52:40.428 INFO - Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
13:52:50.429 INFO - Shutting down
13:52:50.429 INFO - Stopping Safari
13:52:50.486 INFO - Stopping server
13:52:50.486 INFO - Stopping server
13:52:50.487 INFO - Shutdown complete
13:52:50.487 INFO - Shutting down
13:52:50.487 INFO - Stopping server
13:52:50.487 INFO - Shutdown complete
13:52:50.492 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'addteqs-Mini.addteq.com', ip: '10.1.232.198', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:58)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:175)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'addteqs-Mini.addteq.com', ip: '10.1.232.198', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10058 ms
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'addteqs-Mini.addteq.com', ip: '10.1.232.198', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:121)
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:76)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:53)
... 14 more
13:52:50.494 WARN - Exception: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10058 ms
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'addteqs-Mini.addteq.com', ip: '10.1.232.198', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
^C14:10:09.164 INFO - Shutting down...
```

Answer (score 2):

Please upgrade the selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar to [3.6](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), also make sure you are using selenium 3. please remove any webdriver extensions you have on safari.